# Github action rsync aspcore app is not deploying wwwroot files

Tags: asp.net-core, github-actions

I have an aspcore .net7 application that I have CI into a github action which works find and rsync to my linux server. Everything deploys correctly onto the server except for the wwwroot files.

[EDIT] Noticed that when I mark a file in the wwwroot as always copy or copy if newer in the properties then it uploads so it is a build copy issue. How can I tell the project to copy the wwwroot file to the release folder?

Here is my action:

```
jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
     - uses: actions/checkout@v1
     - name: Setup .NET Core
       uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
       with:
        dotnet-version: 7.x
        
     - name: Build app
       run: dotnet build --configuration Release
       
     - name: Deploy to server
       id: deploy
       uses: Pendect/action-rsyncer@v1.1.0
       env:
         DEPLOY_KEY: ${{secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}}
       with:
         flags: '-avzr --delete'
         options: ''
         ssh_options: ''
         src: 'WEBEXAMPLE/bin/Release/net7.0/'
         dest: '${{ secrets.SSH_USER }}@${{ secrets.SSH_HOST }}:/var/www/html'
```

Answer (score 0):

So it seems to add this to the proj file solves the issue. Anyone has better solutions let me know.

```
<ItemGroup>
        <Content Update="wwwroot\**" 
                 CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
    </ItemGroup>
```